# Vue method scroll div to top

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I am learning `vue`. I have the following method where I add a chat message to a div with `id="toolbar-chat"`. This div allows scrolling on y axis and I would like the div to jump to the top every time a new message is added. Why is my JS not working?

```
    document.getElementById("toolbar-chat").scrollTop = 0;
```

My `vue` method:

```
    methods: {
        addMessage(message) {
            this.messages.unshift(message);

            document.getElementById("toolbar-chat").scrollTop = 0;

            axios.post(chat_send_route, message)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data);
            });

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is happening due to way vue updates the dom asynchronously. See [Reacivity in depth(Async update Queue)](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html)

- To reflect changes immediately use `vm.$nextTick(callback)`
- instead of querying the dom element using `document.getElementById()` I recommend add a `ref` attribute to your `toolbar-chat` element and reference it in your method using `this.$refs`. See [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) for more on `ref` attribute

  ```
    <div id="toolbar-chat" ref="toolbarChat"></div>
  ```

So you method should be

```
methods: {
    addMessage(message) {
        this.messages.unshift(message);
        this.$nextTick(() => {
            this.$refs.toolbarChat.scrollTop = 0;
        });

        axios.post(chat_send_route, message)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data);
        });

    }
}
```

Here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t8k1991a/)

Comment: Should be `this.$refs.toolbarChat.$el.scrollTop = 0`

Comment: not working.this.$nextTick(() => {
            this.$refs.container.scrollTop = 0;
          });                                                                                                                                                     <div class="content-main-root" id="content-main-root" ref="container"></div>

Answer (score 12):

Here is my solution :

One global div in main container

```
<div id="topDiv"></div>
```

One global function put in the Vue prototype :

```
Vue.prototype.$scrollTop = function () {
  var element = document.getElementById("topDiv");
  var top = element.offsetTop;
  window.scrollTo(0, top);
}
```

The same anchor everywhere :

```
<a @click="$scrollTop">Go to the top</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is old, but for someone who want to find solution like me:

```
addMessage(message) {
    this.messages.unshift(message);
    this.$nextTick(() => {
        // block: 'end' will scroll to top of element instead of bottom
        this.$refs.toolbarChat.$el.scrollIntoView({ block: 'end', scrollBehavior: 'smooth' });
    });

    axios.post(chat_send_route, message)
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
    });

}
```

Comment: This should be an accepted answer. Using `scrollIntoView()` is more practical and supported in all modern browsers.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to scroll with animated way;

- Add  scrollTo with an object parameter
- Check your ref element ( in my case $refs[refName][0] )
- If you need to use scroll one more place, add into global scope. (Vue.prototype.$toScroll) then use ( $toScroll() )

Here is the basic usage.

```
<a @click="toScroll('aKeyValue',0)"></a>

<div  :ref="'aKeyValue'"  class="scrollable">...</div>
```

This is the method, you can use everywhere.

```
toScroll(refName,position){
   this.messages.unshift(message);
   this.$nextTick(() => {
       this.$refs[refName][0].scrollTo({ top: position, behavior: 'smooth' });
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this to make it work:

```
document.body.scrollTop = 0; // For Safari
document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0; // For Chrome, Firefox, IE and Opera
```